# Alignment of button is not coming proper in right side and size of right component is too much

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jpanel, jcheckbox

I wrote a program which create a Frame which will display  a Control panel and Visual panel.But buttons in control panel is taking too much space. So any body has any idea how to fix it ?? Given is the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class generates and displays a visualization of a Sierpinski
 *
 */
public class tOpost
{
    private JFrame window;
    private JTextField depthTextField;
    private Canvas visual;


    // declare and initialize default values
    private int canvasSize = 512;


    /**
     * Creates a new window and displays a visualization of a Mandelbrot set
     */
    public tOpost()
    {
        // create new window

        window = new JFrame("Sierpinski Visulaizer");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        // create main panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));

        // create textfields with labels
        JPanel depthField = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        depthField.add(new JLabel("Recursive Depth: "));
        depthTextField = new JTextField("");
        depthTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,25));
        depthField.add(depthTextField);


       // create comboBoxes
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        String[] colorText= {"Blue", "Green"};
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel[] jPanels = new JPanel[5];
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            JPanel depthColorPanel = new JPanel();
            depthColorPanel.add(new JLabel("Color " + (i + 1) + ": "));
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(colorText);
            comboBox.setSelectedItem("Blue");
            depthColorPanel.add(comboBox);
            jPanels[i] = depthColorPanel;
        }

        JPanel randomColorPanel = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox randomColorButton = new JCheckBox("Randomize color at each level");
            randomColorButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        randomColorButton.setSelected(false);
        randomColorPanel.add(randomColorButton);

        // create panel for controls
         panel2.add(depthField);
        for (JPanel panel : jPanels) {
            panel2.add(panel);
        }
        panel2.add(randomColorPanel);

        // create button
        JPanel germinatePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton germinateButton = new JButton("Draw");
        germinatePanel.add(germinateButton);

        mainPanel.add(panel2);
        mainPanel.add(germinatePanel);


        // create canvas for visualization
        visual = new Canvas();
        visual.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        visual.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasSize, canvasSize));
        mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
         mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,canvasSize));

        mainPanel.setLocation(750, 250);
        // pack widgets and display window
        window.add(visual);
        window.add(mainPanel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(mainPanel.getSize().getHeight()+","+ mainPanel.getSize().getWidth());
    }


    /**
     * Draws Triangle.
     *
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param s
     * @param color
     */


    /**
     * Starts the program by creating a new instance of the Triangle class.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        new tOpost();
    }
}
```

Comment: thisis question about LayoutManager, for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), with reduce another errors came from CustomisedColor,

Comment: sorry forgot to add those classes now added needed class.

Comment: For better help just post an SSCCE with your UI code without any of your logic code, so we only need to go through a few lines of code iso through a few hundreds

Comment: update with SSCCE without any logic.

Answer (score 2):

1. don't mixing [AWT Components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) with [Swing JComponents](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/index.html), since is possible, but still caused with a few issues
2. don't declare for `mainPanel.setSize(100,100);`, let this is job for proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
3. `JPanel depthField = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());`, [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) accepting `PreferredSize` that came from [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
4. `panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) accepting `PreferredSize` that returns [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
5. JPanel has implemented [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) by default (without any definitions of `LayoutManager`)
6. you have to override proper method for [Painting in the standard Java GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

   - for AWT Components use method `paint()`
   - for Swing JComponents use method `paintComponent()`

.

.

EDIT

.

.

7. this code will help you with workaround for JComboBox

[image][image]

[image]

code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

class ColorComboBoxEditor implements ComboBoxEditor {

    final protected JButton editor;
    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    ColorComboBoxEditor(Color initialColor) {
        editor = new JButton("");
        editor.setBackground(initialColor);
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color currentBackground = editor.getBackground();
                Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(editor, "Color Chooser", currentBackground);
                if ((color != null) && (currentBackground != color)) {
                    editor.setBackground(color);
                    fireActionEvent(color);
                }
            }
        };
        editor.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getEditorComponent() {
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem() {
        return editor.getBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setItem(Object newValue) {
        if (newValue instanceof Color) {
            Color color = (Color) newValue;
            editor.setBackground(color);
        } else {
            try {
                Color color = Color.decode(newValue.toString());
                editor.setBackground(color);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    protected void fireActionEvent(Color color) {
        Object listeners[] = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == ActionListener.class) {
                ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(editor, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, color.toString());
                ((ActionListener) listeners[i + 1]).actionPerformed(actionEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ColorCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    private DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
    private final static Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(0, 20);

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel renderer = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof Color) {
            renderer.setBackground((Color) value);
        }
        if (cellHasFocus || isSelected) {
            renderer.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        } else {
            renderer.setBorder(null);
        }
        renderer.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        return renderer;
    }
}

class ColorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo {

    public ColorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo() {
        Color colors[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW};
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color JComboBox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(colors);
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setRenderer(new ColorCellRenderer());
        Color color = (Color) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        ComboBoxEditor editor = new ColorComboBoxEditor(color);
        comboBox.setEditor(editor);
        frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground((Color) comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                Color selectedColor = (Color) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                label.setBackground(selectedColor);
            }
        };
        comboBox.addActionListener(actionListener);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ColorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo colorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo = new ColorComboBoxEditorRendererDemo();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```